# Elasticsearch - How to make JavaScript client response more than 10 items

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch

I am using [JavaScript client](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-reference-2-4.html) for Elasticsearch. I have a problem with request:

```
client.search({
      index: applicationIndex,
      type: applicationType,
      body: {
        query: {
          match_all : {}
        }
      }
    })
    .then(function(res){
      return {res: res};
    });
```

It is not returning more than 10 items. How can I return all (actually there are 21 items) ?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the documentation it states that `size` defaults to 10. Add `size` to your search object and set its value to `21`.

Try this

```
client.search({
      index: applicationIndex,
      type: applicationType,
      size: 21,
      body: { 
        query: {
          match_all : {}
        }
      }
    })
    .then(function(res){
      return {res: res};
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also manage the pagination with a "from" parameter adding with the "size" one :)

```
client.search({
  index: applicationIndex,
  type: applicationType,
  size: 10,
  from: 10,
  body: { 
    query: {
      match_all : {}
    }
  }
})
.then(function(res){
  return {res: res};
});
```

Here it will return the element between 10 and 20 :)

Have fun with elasticsearch :)